# RShiny - downloadButton Module not updating with new data

Tags: r, shiny, widget, shiny-reactivity

I'm having issues with a download button module downloading the correct dataset. Using it once it downloads as you'd expect, but once widget values change, and the download button is re-clicked, it downloads the previously selected variables, almost as if it's caching the values and not updating them. Same thing with the plot/filename titles. 
Everything is wrapped in `reactive` as necessary, and the plot updates as the values change. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong. Cheers!

Note: issue persists even without usage of modules.

Reprex:

```
# Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)


# Load sources
source(here("dwnld buttons.R"))


# Load data
data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      varSelectInput(inputId = "x_var",
                     data = mtcars,
                     label = "Select x var"),
      varSelectInput(inputId = "y_var",
                     data = mtcars,
                     selected = names(mtcars)[2],
                     label = "Select y var")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot"),
      dwnldButtonUI(id = "download")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  
  plot1_data <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% 
      select(input$x_var, input$y_var) %>% 
      rename("x" = input$x_var,
             "y" = input$y_var)
  })
  
  labels <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(c(input$x_var, input$y_var), {
    labels$title1 <- paste(input$y_var, "vs", input$x_var)
  })
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(data = plot1_data(),
           aes(x = x,
               y = y))+
      geom_point()+
      labs(title = labels$title1)
    
  }
    
  )
  
  dwnldButtonServer(id = "download",
                    file_name = labels$title1,
                    graph_df = plot1_data()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

### Module ###

dwnldButtonUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    downloadButton(outputId = ns("dwnldBtn"),
                   label = "")
  )
}

dwnldButtonServer <- function(id, file_name, graph_df){
  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      output$dwnldBtn <- downloadHandler(
        
        filename = function() {
          paste(file_name, ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(graph_df, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
      )
    }
  )
  
  
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the `reactive` itself (not its value) to the module and then use its value (not the `reactive` itself, inside the module server.  So `dwnldButtonServer(..., graph_df = plot1_data)` and `write.csv(graph_df(), file, row.names = FALSE)`.  Your code is not reproducible because you reference an external file for the module code i the main app but provide the code directly in your question.  Thus we can't copy, paste and run...

Comment: Hi @Limey that's perfect! I'm now having trouble with the `reactiveValues` in the filename for the `downloadButton`. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  1:  "I'm having trouble" is not specific enough to permit diagnosis, especially as the code in your example has changed and 2: when it was never reproducible anyway.  A new problem should be posted as a new question.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: Thanks for that @Limey. I've solved both issues of downloading the old dataset, and old filename, [after widget values have changed] using the method you've suggested above. Will post an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilising @Limey's comment, the solution can be extended to include to update both the download data, and filename, after widget values have been changed. This involves passing the `reactive` (not its value) to the module, and then accessing its value (not the `reactive` itself). See below:

```
# Here we try and recreate a simplified version of the download button error #

# Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
# library(here)


# Load sources
# source(here("dwnld buttons.R"))


# Load data
data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      varSelectInput(inputId = "x_var",
                     data = mtcars,
                     label = "Select x var"),
      varSelectInput(inputId = "y_var",
                     data = mtcars,
                     selected = names(mtcars)[2],
                     label = "Select y var")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot"),
      dwnldButtonUI(id = "download")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  
  plot1_data <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% 
      select(input$x_var, input$y_var) %>% 
      rename("x" = input$x_var,
             "y" = input$y_var)
  })
  
  labels <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(c(input$x_var, input$y_var), {
    labels$title1 <- paste(input$y_var, "vs", input$x_var)
  })
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(data = plot1_data(),
           aes(x = x,
               y = y))+
      geom_point()+
      labs(title = labels$title1
           )
    
  })
  
  labels_title1 <- reactive({labels$title1})

  
  dwnldButtonServer(id = "download",
                    # File_name and graph_df is passed the reactive, not value
                    file_name = labels_title1,
                    graph_df = plot1_data
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



# Module UI
dwnldButtonUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    downloadButton(outputId = ns("dwnldBtn"),
                   label = "")
  )
}

# Module server
dwnldButtonServer <- function(id, file_name, graph_df){
  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      output$dwnldBtn <- downloadHandler(
        
        filename = function() {
          # Access the reactive value using ()
          paste(file_name(), ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        
        content = function(file) {
          # Access the reactive value using ()
          write.csv(graph_df(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
      )
    }
  )
  
}
```